# Why does the preferred languages array contain only one item?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization, internationalization

I use the following code in my app to print the preferred languages at startup:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray* languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    NSLog(@"%@", languages);
}
```

The list only contain one item though. Changing the language in the simulator has no effect. The strange thing is that if I start over with a new project the exact same code above prints a full list of languages. How come my app doesn't get the full list of languages? Is there a setting in XCode I might have switched?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

I had most probably played around with the NSUserDefaults and changed the list myself, not knowing it would stick permanently. Removing the app from the simulator and letting XCode upload it again solved the problem. Good to know when running into similar problems.